# Expected Microsoft Graph API client application with ClientId...does not have required permissions

Tags: postgresql, azure

Trying to deploy a flexible server Postgres DB in Azure and I'm hitting this error:

```
"code": "AadAuthEnableFailedDueToMissingGraphApiAccessPrincipal", "message": "Expected 
Microsoft Graph API client application with ClientId = some_client_id is not found in the TenantId = our_tenant_id, or 
does not have required permissions."
```

So, I recognize the TenantId, `our_tenant_id` but not the `some_client_id`. It's not the object ID of my user. And I'm a subscription owner so I should have permissions to do this.

Does anyone know of a way to troubleshoot this? How to ID who/what that client ID belongs to?

Comment: You need to register a client application first and it will generate the ClientId. The client application is what allows exposure of Microsoft data to your application. I have not done this from scratch in a few years, but there are some good resources to check out:
(this example uses Azure Health Data Services but that shouldn't matter, the part we care about is the "Register a new application" section)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application

(another tutorial)
https://geeksarray.com/blog/get-azure-subscription-tenant-client-id-client-secret

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue occurs if the below prerequisite was not performed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication?source=recommendations#prerequisites

Our product group are working on removing this requirement soon but until then customers must complete the prerequisite to avoid this error.

Please check and let me know if you have any questions.